# Barcode web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to use this web service which creates a barcode and I am getting this exception error

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'BarCodeService.BarCodeSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

My Code

```
byte[] barCodeByte = new BarCodeSoapClient().Code39(ticketNumber.ToString(), 6, true, "Ticket BarCode");
```

[Url of webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/barcode.asmx?op=Code39)

I dont know what an endpoint name is. Could someone explain please ?

Comment: What is the client? win form ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan The client is a website with mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the endpoint name because there is more than one of them (see the WSDL).

Try this:

```
var client = new BarCodeSoapClient("BarCodeSoap");
byte[] barCodeByte = client.Code39("abc", 6, true, "Ticket BarCode");
```